# What is the purpose of timestamps in unified diffs?

Tags: diff, patch, file-format

[An Example of Unified Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Example-Unified.html):

```
--- lao 2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800
+++ tzu 2002-02-21 23:30:50.442260588 -0800
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
-The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
-The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
 The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
-The Named is the mother of all things.
+The named is the mother of all things.
+
 Therefore let there always be non-being,
   so we may see their subtlety,
 And let there always be being,
@@ -9,3 +8,6 @@
 The two are the same,
 But after they are produced,
   they have different names.
+They both may be called deep and profound.
+Deeper and more profound,
+The door of all subtleties!
```

What is the purpose of the timestamps (e.g. `2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800`) that appear after the file names? Are they mandatory? Can I safely remove them? What are the consequences of faking the time (e.g. using a future time)?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the purpose of the timestamps (e.g. 2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800) that appear after the file names?

To know when files were changed. To sync files' timestamps for different people working on the same project.

> Are they mandatory? Can I safely remove them?

No, yes.

> What are the consequences of faking the time (e.g. using a future time)?

None that I'm aware of. Also check `man patch` for `-Z or --set-utc`